# Using @local_variable in CSHTML code in asp-page

Tags: razor-pages

I develop ASP.Net Core 2.1 RazorPages web application. I want parametrize the the value of asp-page tag helper.

So I use following code in cshtml file. There is a `del_link` local variable defined in begining of file. This variable is late used as parameter for second `asp-page` tag helper.

```
@page
@{
    string del_link = "/UnloadDelete";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a asp-page="/UnloadEdit">Details</a>
        <a asp-page=@del_link>Delete</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP.Net Razor generate following HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="/UnloadEdit">Details</a>
        <a href="">Delete</a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in HTML code, `asp-page="/UnloadEdit"` is properly rendered to HTML code, but `asp-page=@del` not, it is rendered to `<a href="">`. How I can use local variable for asp-page tag helper in Razor Pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass a page name to the `asp-page` attribute. So what you are trying to do is not supported. If `@del_link` renders a relative URL, you can pass that to the `href` attribute instead. There may be other suitable solutions, depending on why you feel the need to use `@del_link` at all.